# Generate coronograph speckle pattern in mathematica

Tags: graphics, matrix, image-processing, random

## How to simulate the radial coronograph "speckle-noise" in this image?

[image: 3 exoplanets]

> The 3 circled objects are exoplanets.
> Their star has been blocked out by a coronagraph,
> resulting in optical noise known as "speckles".

### I am interested in generating the noise (the grainy stuff).

It has to look similar (for the purpose of training a Neural Network to ignore it)

> I am looking for ideas about how to generating such speckle noise in Mathematica.

---

Here is one approach using the Fourier transform of random phasors.
The trouble is that the speckle elements are not radially oriented in a circle like the image above.

```
(* Program for Simulating Speckle Formation by Free Space Propagation*)

n = 2^8;
(* Linear dimension of the nxn array to be used.*)

k = 2^2;
(*number of samples (in one dimension) per speckle. *)

start = Table[E^(I 2 \[Pi] * Random[]), {n/k}, {n/k}];
(*generate an n/k \[Times] n/k array of random phasors *)

scatterArray = PadRight[start, {n, n}];
(*pad the phasr array with zeros*)

(*the scattering spot is a square of size n/k\[Times]n/k  *)
speckleField = Fourier[scatterArray];

(* Find the FFT of the padded array *)
(*this is the speckle field in the observation plane*)
speckleIntensity = Abs[speckleField]^2;

(*find the intensity of the observed speckle field*)
ListDensityPlot[speckleIntensity]
```

[image]

could I stretch it into a circle? Or print it on the side of a cone and view it from above?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path. After you generate your noise field, you can mask it with a circular function. For example, I used a modified Gaussian function to create the mask:

```
decay = 20; (* Customizable decay factor *)
decayExp = 1/4; (* Customizable decay exponent *)
mask = Table[
   Exp[-N[((decay x/n)^2 + (decay y/n)^2)]^(decayExp)],
   {y, -n/2, n/2 - 1}, {x, -n/2, n/2 - 1}];
```

Then you multiply your field with the mask and plot it:

```
speckleIntensityMasked = speckleIntensity*mask;

ListDensityPlot[speckleIntensityMasked, 
 RegionFunction -> ((#1 - n/2)^2 + (#2 - n/2)^2 >= (n/4)^2 &), 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: masked density plot]